# Address family for hostname not supported in python statsd client 3.2, but ip provided

Tags: python, statsd

Python code:

```
    try:
        self.__statsd = TCPStatsClient(self.Host,self.Port,self.Prefix,None)
        self.__statsd.connect()
    except Exception as e:
        print "Exception while connecting to StatsD: %s", str(e) 
        print "Failed to establish connection to StatsD server at %s:%s", self.Host, str(self.Port)
```

When I run "/usr/share/python/myproject/bin/python myproject.py", error is as following (10.1.1.25 is used for statsd host):

```
2015-10-21 16:20:28 Exception while connecting to StatsD: [Errno -9] Address family for hostname not supported
2015-10-21 16:20:28 Failed to establish connection to StatsD server at 10.1.1.25:8125
```

When I run "/home/myadmin/.virtualenvs/myproject-dev/bin/python myproject.py", **everything is OK**.

**UPDATE**

My old code does not work under 3.2. Now my code is updated as following:

```
 self.__statsd = TCPStatsClient(host=self.Host,port=self.Port,prefix=self.Prefix,timeout=None)
```

Comment: Check versions of statsd in your environments.

Comment: @EugeneSoldatov version are 3.2 and 3.1

Comment: Try to use same version on both environments.